# Yii framework urlManager rewrite rules

Tags: yii

I have a url that looks like this:

```
<controller>/<action>/param/value
```

and I want it to like something like this:

```
param/value
```

How can it be achieved?

I tried this rule but not sure if it's ok (controller is account and action is index).

```
'user/<user:.*>' => 'account/index/user/test'
```

Comment: `urlManager` works the other way around, what you need are `.htaccess`  redirects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I uderstand your question correctly, you want to handle URL's like this:

```
mysite.domain/user/username123
```

And call **actionIndex** in **AccountController** with param **User**, which (in this case) equals **"username123"**

In this case you can try the rule below:

```
'user/<user:.*>' => 'account/index/<user>'
```

But maybe you will need to change the declaration if your action:

```
function actionIndex($user){
    // code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid putting params into action signatures as yii doens't go about processing actions with mismatching signatures [gracefully] at all... In fact, putting $user in will bind that action to always need a $user specified and if you ever decide to change your functionality, tracking down why your action isn't being called would be harder than determining why your $_GET isn't set... I would suggest in stead of adding the $user into the signature, just do something as follows in your action.

```
//will always run on /user/<USER:.*>
function actionIndex(){
    $user = isset($_GET['user'])?$_GET['user']:NULL;
    if(!is_null($user)){
        //your user specific account action..
    }else{
        //handle your error gracefully..
    }
}
```

This approach lets your action be more versatile. The URL rule should be as follows:

```
'user/<user:.*>' => 'account/index/user/<user>' //user is defined as a get...
```

Hope that helps && happy coding!